# Trouble finding how I can plug in this Molex connector from a Laptop Fan

Tags: power, batteries, heat, fan, laptop

I recently bought this fan, I am trying to power it for an external project that doesn't revolve around laptops; however, I don't know how to get power to the fan without cutting off the molex connector and stripping the wires.

I know this is a female molex connector, but I can't find any male heads that even remotely fit this type of product, so I ask you guys if you know of the specific molex connector that I can use to plug into this connector and get power to it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you post a close-up of the connector?  How do you know it's Molex? Does it have any markings? How far apart are the pins/sockets? Also, if you say what make of laptop it's designed for someone might know from that. Laptops rarely use the standard connectors that desktops use.

Comment: @winny that's not even what op is asking . It's a part identification for the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Check the pitch and find something that matches on digikey (you might end up checking 20+ mechanical drawings, but thats the nature of these problems. Another option is to unsolder a connector from a laptop motherboard, just find a connector with the same pitch.

Third option, if the connectors aren't to small the 0.1" jumpers might fit into the end of that connector and into a breadboard.

But it would be far easier to learn how to use a soldering iron, find a 4 wire connector that you can use, and splice the wires. Soldering irons can be found for as low as 10$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the connectors that you use on breadboards, plug one end into the connectors on the fan and solder the other end to your power source, I often use this method on connectors on items that I want to use as it was originally intended as well as for my own uses.